# Flash player will not install corectly

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, adobe-flash

I am trying to install flash player on my MacBook Air.  I have been using flash player  without any problems.  Recently when I tried to use a program that uses flash a popup appears that says the plug in failed to load.  I tried to reinstall shockwave flash and it said that it installed but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome does not use the system flash, it has it's own copy of Flash. Try deleting and reinstalling the Google Chrome app.